# How to properly notify user of successful file upload (Express, NodeJS)

Tags: node.js, express

I have a form where a user can upload a .xslx file to the database:

```
<form id="form1" action="/upload/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="file" id="control" name="XLupload">Choose File</input>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit"></submit>
</form>
```

And here is the code that handles the upload in Express:

```
router.post('/upload', excel_upload, function(req, res) {
   ...code that extracts relevant data...and then uses insertObj as a callback...
    // Inserts object w/ extracted data from file into the database
    function insertObj(obj) {
        insertionCollection.insertOne(obj, function(err, result) {
            if (err)
                throw err;
            else
                res.redirect('/');
        });
    };
  }
```

I was wondering what the best way would be to give the user a feedback message(perhaps an alert) on successful file upload on the front-end.  Right now it works fine but it just seems like the page refreshed when a file is uploaded.

Thanks!

Comment: `res.redirect('/upload-success.html')`.

Comment: On a related note, throwing on `err` is certainly not a good idea.